# Cache reference to local files

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

I'm experimenting with the Filereader API and Webaudio API and am building a basic audio player where a user can upload mp3's and play them back etc.

It would be great if the files that the user uploaded would persist, so if they refreshed the page or navigated away, the files didn't need to be re-uploaded.

Is this possible without uploading the files to a server?

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is. You could use [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) for that purpose. You can store blob data using it. However, you should notice that support in Safari is [buggy](https://gist.github.com/nolanlawson/08eb857c6b17a30c1b26) - this means there are some quirks that may result in serious issues with your app for users that use this browser. If you need to get things done quickly, I suggest you to use either [localForage](https://github.com/mozilla/localForage) or [IDBWrapper](https://github.com/jensarps/IDBWrapper) with [this shim](https://github.com/axemclion/IndexedDBShim).

Comment: Nice one! I attempted to use local storage, but stringifying the object didn't seem to work. This works like a charm using localforage. Thanks!